# onDataChange method did not work in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I working on an Android studio application and I used a Firebase real-time database. And I have a problem and ask for help.. The table name in the database is `Hospital` and the properties are `hospital_name`,`hospital_code`,`hospital_password`,`hospital_phone`,`hospital_email`.

The information added successfully but the problem that I could not retrieve the information from the database (hospital name and hospital code) and I searched and used different ways, but still the problem exist. The should code retrieve the information from `Hospital` table and show it in the application.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    TextView reg;

    EditText email,password;
    Button loginBt;
    Database db;
    String emailString,passwordString;
    TextView regText;
    TextView name,code;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital").child("ABA");
        db = new Database();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logInEmail);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
        regText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_text);
        loginBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logInButton);
       /* loginBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });*/
        regText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createAccount();
            }
        });
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hospitalNameMain);
        code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hospitalCodeMain);
        loginBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                show();
            }
        });


    }

    private void show() {

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital").child("QCH");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"log in ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String hospitalName = dataSnapshot.child("hospital_name").getValue().toString();
                String hospitalCode = dataSnapshot.child("hospital_code").getValue().toString();
                name.setText(hospitalName);
                code.setText(hospitalCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void createAccount() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Database Structure:

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure and responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: https://d.top4top.net/p_1140z9yph1.png

Comment: Do you want to get the hospital name and hospital code from a single record or from all records?

Comment: for a single record where the hospital code = "QCH"

Comment: If you run this code in a debugger, and put a breakpoint on `name.setText(hospitalName);`, what is the value of `hospitalName` that you see in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> for a single record where the hospital code = "QCH"

Please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Hospital").child("QCH");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String hospitalName = dataSnapshot.child("hospital_name").getValue(String.class);
        String hospitalCode = dataSnapshot.child("hospital_code").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, hospitalName + " / " + hospitalCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
hjkk / QCH
```

Comment: this is the logical

Comment: I don't understand, what's purpose of this screenshot? Have you tried my solution above?

Comment: Thank yoooooou it is working know, thank you.. I am so happy, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

don't use 
`.child("Hospital").child("QCH")` for reference

your `ref` will be on this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital")
```

you will get all the records in `dataSnapshot`

**Edit**

try to cast dataSnapshot into your Hospital model & get the values from that

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital").child("QCH")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get particular hospital by ID.

Use following query.

```
databaseRef.orderByChild("hostpital_code").equals(yourCode);
```

So your full query will be:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital").orderByChild("hostpital_code").equals("QCH");
```

Do let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: There is no need to use a query since the keys under `Hospital` node are unique. A query like that will never return more than one result. In this case, only a `DatabaseReference` is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Hospital");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //use for loop iterator here 
    for(DataSnapshot data1:dataSnapshot){
     //this will print the key and value in console use it as you wish.
        log.i("TAG",data1.child().getKey()+"::"+data1.child.getValue()); 
    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```